# Videos on SharePoint

Tags: video, media-streaming

I have many videos on SharePoint. the problem is that when a user play the video he has to wait for it load completely and then watch. basically the video is not buffering. how can i enable the buffering/streaming option on SharePoint.

proof of concept: i monitored the videos loading completely from the developer tool and started playing the hole video was downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Video buffering is supported in SharePoint. 
The out of the box video player webpart supports buffering, however there are a lot of people who have experienced issues trying to buffer videos of large size.

You can probably try [this](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.in/2012/12/sharepoint-2013-videos-in-sharepoint.html)

Source:  [Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i enabled the BLOB cache from the web.config on the front end server which immediately enabled the buffering on SharePoint.

for more info follow this link: [TN Configure cache settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you use sharepoint content query webpart to show videos from Asset Library, videos will be open in a pop up automatically instead of downloading it (as it happens in Content Editor Webpart). It may be behaviour of html5 enabled browser. But i tried this and it works